# Google Geocoding Without API Key

Tags: user-interface, user-input, google-geocoder

I'm using Google Geocoding merely to retrieve Location names so the users can Input the place they live (Country/City) into a form, i'm not actually "Geocoding".

Following the example on: [Angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) The Typeahead Section

I have two concerns:

1) I'm not sending an API Key, but it still works... is this OK?
(I've red that is no longer necessary in the forums...)

2) Is there a better way of doing this? maybe with a Database of places or some 3rd party service to provide Country/City Names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [This database](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) is what you are looking for, it provides you with all coutries their countryCode,region,city,postalCode,latitude,longitude,metroCode and areaCode
The problem is that it is a long list so you have to be a bit creative in how to display these informations to the user ( an autocompleeter may do the trick)

I you want somthing else try OSM they have many services like [this](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?city=tunis&countrycodes=tn&limit=9&format=xml) u need to give it country code and city so it give you the location. Or in your case you have lang+lati and you need the adress so i think u can use [this](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=36.799969&lon=10.171087&zoom=18&addressdetails=1)

Hope this helps you

Comment: I think this will do, ty!